# Can I use array variable to define typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let say I have a constant variable

```
const STATUS = {
    ACTIVE: "ACTIVE",
    DELETED: "DELETED",
  }
```

And I have a function which input is status

```
const handleStatus = (status) {
//do some thing
}
```

I want to define interface for `status` just accept 'ACTIVE' and 'DELETED' so I have to manually define like bellow

```
type status = 'ACTIVE' | 'DELETED'
const handleStatus = (status : status) {
//do some thing
}
```

Can I do something like

```
type status = Object.values(STATUS)
```

Thanks!

Edit :
I define `type status = (typeof STATUS)[keyof typeof STATUS]`
But when I try to check if status is valid

```
const validStatus = Object.values(STATUS)
if(!validStatus.includes(status)) {
  //do something
}
```

Typescript throw error

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type ...
```

Comment: You probably want an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're 2 options for you. As a suggestion in comment to switch using `enum` in this case, another way is to use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) keyword in terms of still wanting to have a string literal as type:

```
type Status = keyof typeof STATUS;
```

PS: If you prefer the values as type rather than the keys, you need to tweak a bit more:

```
const STATUS = {...} as const // mark it as constant

type Status = (typeof STATUS)[keyof typeof STATUS];
```

**Answer for newly added request**

Looks like misunderstand between typing vs its value. You can't set a type as value which means you have to create a variable with the type you already defined (Don't define a type name as lowercase `status`) so here's the example:

```
type Status = (typeof STATUS)[keyof typeof STATUS];

// this is the value which needs to create with your created type
const status: Status = 'ACTIVE';

// you can set this type as: `Status[]` or 
// you don't need to do so cause
// tsc can infer correct type as `Status[]`
const validStatus = Object.values(STATUS);

if(!validStatus.includes(status)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @tmhao2005 I have another problem with this. Could you check my edit. Thanks

Comment: I just added the additional explanation and code snippet for you :)